# Prevent div from new line in table th

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

As you can see the progressbar is not in line with the text.
The bar is an seperate div:

```
            <th width="300px">
    Atv opgenomen / totaal: 22:48 h / 62.0 h
            </th>
            <th>
<?php
                echo '<div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="'.$perc_bar_atv.'" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: '.$perc_bar_atv.'%;">
                    '.round($perc_bar_atv).'%
                  </div>
                </div>';
            ?>
        </th>
```

Any suggestions how to get this inline? I have tried `style="display: inline"` That works but removes some the markup
[image]

`style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:center"`gives
[image]

Comment: To show html between `<?php` and `?>` you need to use `echo`

Comment: Did you tried setting style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:center"

Comment: Pls provide CSS rules. It could help. No rules - no solution :)

Comment: @Awais see my updated post.

Comment: @Banzay CSS > `Bootstrap 3`

Comment: @Muiter Can you create a working fiddle of just html without php, and also try `vertical-align:center` on `td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to set proper margin for `.progress` is enough, like this:

```
.progress {
    margin: 10px 0 !important;
}
```

or this

```
.progress {
    margin: auto 0 !important;
}
```

```css
.progress {
    margin: 10px 0 !important;
}
 th {
     border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
<tr>
<th width="300px">
    Atv opgenomen / totaal: 22:48 h / 62.0 h
            </th>
            <th width="300px">
<div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;">50%</div>
                </div>
        </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is indeed an very nice solution!